# Should I peel turmeric?

Tags: spices

I want to know whether there is any need to peel the skin of turmeric from a palatability, taste, food safety or hygiene standpoint? Is there any relevant nutrient content, above that of the turmeric flesh, in what is discarded after peeling?

Comment: Welcome! Unfortunately, this site does not address concerns of nutrition or "health". As such, this question will probably be closed.

Comment: Please kindly refer to which forum should I ask this

Comment: I don't think this general "what is healthy" sort of question is taken by any StackExchange site, sorry. I'm sure there are sites out there that do discuss this sort of thing, but we're not much more likely to know than anyone else.

Comment: I hope my edit wasn't too heavy handed.

Comment: @rackandboneman I don't see how it fixes anything... it's still asking for "nutritional information".

Comment: You really don't like piggybacking in questions huh? :) But nutrient content isn't nutrititional value. I could have fixed the question title though...

Comment: @rackandboneman I don't know how you define the difference between "nutritional value" and "nutritional content" (I personally would treat the two terms as roughly the same), but the question is still off topic after your edit. The difference is in who defines what is "relevant" nutrient content. If the OP asks "what percentage of vitamin X is discarded", that would be one of the exceptions which are on-topic. If the question expects that the answerers come up with the idea "vitamin X is relevant, I will say how much of it is discarded", then it's offtopic, like any other nutrition question.

Comment: Always thought "is there iron in cumin?" would be valid here, though "is iron good for you? is it good for you when eating cumin or spinach or a battleaxe?" wouldn't?

Comment: @rackandboneman yes, your understanding is correct. But the question here is not at all equivalent to "is there iron in cumin". It asks about "any relevant nutrient content" and not about a given nutrient. So the person doing the answering would have to define what should be considered "relevant nutrient content" before being able to write an answer, and that makes it off topic.

Answer (score 2):

To address a few points:

- palatability, taste

There's not much taste to the "skin."  As with ginger, it's more of a texture thing.  For larger/more mature pieces, the skin can be thicker and perhaps create more of a texture contrast.  I think most people tend to peel it, but it's not strictly necessary.

- food safety or hygiene

No significant food safety issue.  Hygiene is about the same as any root/rhizome vegetable.  That is to say: anything in the dirt will likely be on the skin, so if you don't want to eat the dirt (and what may be in it), scrub well or peel.  If you are concerned about possible pesticides or something else in the dirt, peeling is likely efficient for removing any on the exterior.

As for nutrition, after a few searches, I haven't found good information that implies any significantly different nutrients in the skin.

Comment: I assume it'd be like ginger -- no need to peel it on young ginger (when the skin is paper thin, and you could easily cut through it with a thumbnail), but peel it on older bits so you're not stuck with really fibrous bits.